# how to organize more than 40000 mp3 files in wp8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to place about 45000 mp3 files in my wp8 app, 
    all of them are sound effect and less than 5k bytes,
    however the total space are more than 150m bytes.

I think there are 2 ways to store them.

1. **store each of mp3 as a separate file**, it need more than 150m space in logical and actually more than 220m
2. **use a binary file to save all of them in one file**, maybe like below structure:

   ```
   first 4bytes :    --length of mp3 file name;
   first byte[]:     --store the mp3 file name;
   senc  4bytes:     --length of mp3 file;
   senc  byte[]:     --store the real content of mp3;
   ```

and repeat this to append all of them to one file.

It need only 150m , however I have to seek the position of each mp3 file.

Which one you think is better? I prefer to the second solution. However I don't find any api can seek from offset 0 to offset 150*1024*1024,and maybe this will raise performance issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the second option with an index and use of [BinaryReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.io.binaryreader%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). You can seek to a `position` ([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.io.stream.position%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)) in a file (something like this):

```
byte[] mp3File;
// Get the file.
var file = await dataFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync("combined_mp3s.bin");

using (var binReader = new BinaryReader(file))
{
    binReader.Postion = offset; // using your math ...
    var fileName = binReader.ReadString(); (length prefixed string read)
    // or you could read the size on your own and read the characters
    var mp3FileLen = binReader.ReadInt32();
    mp3File = binReader.ReaderBytes(mp3FileLen);        
}
```

I would suggest you have a hash/dictionary of the file names and starting position of the data for each file stored separately so your application can quickly locate the contents of a file without doing a scan.

#### Downloading

You may also want to consider breaking the huge file into some smaller files for a better download experience. You could append to the huge file as the contents of a group or individual file is available on the phone.

Comment: It's available on the Phone: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.io.binaryreader(v=vs.105).aspx.  I also added a suggestion for how to handle the download experience.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your second alternative is that by avoiding the filesystem, you lose a great deal of convenience that the filesystem would afford you.

Perhaps most importantly, you can now (using your proposed data-structure) no longer retrieve a file with a particular name without scanning (potentially) the entire file.

The extra space in the filesystem is probably well used.

Comment: thanks dude, actually Im using the first way now,It's convenient and do not need extra code to handle it.however it need about 5 minutes to extract from the original bigfile (I can not add every mp3 file to asset folder,I just use app to download that bigfile which contains all of mp3 file). and what im worried about is the user maybe feel impatient..